# Drawing a custom bar chart graph in iOS(PowerPlot vs Core plot)

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-plot, bar-chart

I have been looking all around the net for open source graph plot framework for iOS, but I am struggling with it as of now. I have worked on an app and used PowerPlot Graph Plot framework http://powerplot.nua-schroers.de/examples/webtraffic.html

I am trying to draw a bar graph chart showing two years at once without stacking each, like in the image below: As you can see there is a problem of resizeing and the scaling isnt uniform. I would like to make the chart look bigger and the y axis be more formatted.    [image]

Any suggestions because I always hear about core plot also by which you can achieve such(see below), but all i hear about coreplot is flexibility and customization issues.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you've "heard" about core-plot but haven't tried it; It might be just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily produce a bar plot like that with Core Plot. Give it a try and ask specific questions here on StackOverflow if you get stuck.

Comment: CorePlot has a 5MB binary size. Don't feel like adding that overload to my App.